# Bottom border line behind navigationBar dont show in iPhone X

Tags: ios, iphone, iphone-x

I have this problem. I´m working with Xcode 9 and Swift 3. The navigation bar in navigation controller has Translucent check to true. But...

In iPhone 7 simulator the border line behind navigation bar show perfectly but in iPhone X simulator, this line don't show.

Anybody know how resolved it?

[image]